# React, как добавить множество объектов в компонент

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-hook

Есть компонент, в котором один элемент кнопка, как можно добавить  ещё Button, пыталась добавить путём добавления ещё кнопок Button, но у меня выдаёт ошибку если сделать так

```
    const App = (): JSX.Element =>{ <Button variant="contained">test button</Button>
            <Button variant="contained">test button</Button>
    <Button variant="contained">test button</Button>
    <Button variant="contained">test button</Button>
}
```

исходный компонент

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Button } from '@mui/material';

 const App = (): JSX.Element => <Button variant="contained">test button</Button>;

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должен быть один родительский элемент, т.е. нужно все кнопки обернуть в тег div или <>...</>
Вот так:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

const App = (): JSX.Element =>{
    
      return ( 
        <>
        <Button variant="contained">test button</Button>
        <Button variant="contained">test button</Button>
        <Button variant="contained">test button</Button>
        <Button variant="contained">test button</Button>
        </>
      )
  }
  
  export default App;
```